# Build sql query based on input param

Tags: ruby

I am building a SQL query and created a execution method to run it as follows:

```
module Helper
  module Action

    BASE_SQL_QUERY = 'SELECT a,b,c FROM SOME_TABLE'

    SELECT_QUERY = "#{BASE_SQL_QUERY}"

    def self.execute(action:, db_client:, data:)
      db_client.prepare(Helper::Count::SELECT_QUERY).execute
    end
  end
end
```

It is working fine bit I am going to have exact same module and the only different will be in the query. Instead `SELECT a,b,c` it'll be `SELECT count(*)` and everything else will be same.

In execution method action argument will have what action i want to do `action == 'read'` do `SELECT a,b,c` and for `action == count` do `SELECT count(*)`.

What am trying to do is have only one module Action and based on action value build sql. Is it possible to do that? I tried bunch of ways like creating a method and passing action to it and tried to build sql but i get error `dynamic constant assignment` because CONSTANT value can not be in method.

is it possible to build sql based on action value?

Answer (score 0):

Sure it's possible, any existing ORM does exactly that among other things - provide the interface to build sql queries using the language common syntax.

Besides large and scary full-featured ORMs there are some gems that does just the job you're looking for - query building. You could check how they are implemented and borrow some ideas there (for example, https://github.com/izniburak/qruby)